# In SQL - Is there a way to combine or group by an ID without grouping by the case statement

Tags: sql

Sorry if I didn't explain that well.

Here is code:

```
with idt as 

(select sld.id
      , sld.disposition
      , row_number() over (partition BY sld.id  ORDER BY sld.entered_at DESC) row_number
from sld 
order by 1)

select id
     , case when row_number = 1 then disposition end disposition_1
     , case when row_number = 1 then entered_at end entered_at_1
     , case when row_number = 2 then disposition end disposition_2
     , case when row_number = 2 then entered_at end entered_at_2
from idt
```

My current result is:

```
id    disposition_1 entered_at_1 disposition_2 entered_at_2
1255  New            1/1/20
1225                              Working       2/1/20
```

I would like the result to be combined, like this:

```
id    disposition_1 entered_at_1 disposition_2 entered_at_2
1255  New            1/1/20       Working      2/1/20
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate!

```
select id,
       max(case when row_number = 1 then disposition end) as disposition_1
       max(case when row_number = 1 then entered_at end) as entered_at_1
       max(case when row_number = 2 then disposition end) as disposition_2
       max(case when row_number = 2 then entered_at end) as entered_at_2
from idt
group by id;
```